# Evaluate this element tag using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, tags

```
<td class="fc-event-container" colspan="2"\>
<a class="fc-day-grid-event fc-h-event fc-event fc-start fc-end fc-draggable" style="background-color:#FF4500;border-color:#FF4500">
8a 55555-Sovereign Housing-Jn
</a>
</td>
```

How can I get the object under td tag and check the value of a tag then alter value of colspan of td tag?

I was trying to access the element by jQuery selector and I have done this:

```
$('td[class^="fc-event-container"]').each(function (index)
 {                 
  console.log($(this.find('a[class^="fc-day-grid-event"]')));
})
```

Which is returning an array of size 8.
What I want to do is i have to change value of colspan of first index while checking value of firstcol and lastCol which is coming after

```
$('a[class^="fc-day-grid-event"]')[0]['fcSeg']` which is showing value like
`component: DayGrid 
{uid: '3', 
context: {…}, 
dateEnv: DateEnv, 
theme: StandardTheme, 
view: DayGridView, …} 
el: a.fc-day-grid-event.fc-h-event.fc-event.fc-start.fc-end.fc-draggable 
eventRange: {def: {…}, ui: {…}, instance: {…}, range: {…}, isStart: true, …} 
firstCol: 5 
isEnd: true 
isStart: true 
lastCol: 6 
leftCol: 5 
level: 0 
rightCol: 6 
row: 0 
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

Comment: Firstly, you can just use `td.fc-event-container` and `a.fc-day-grid-event` selectors when working with classes. Don't use attribute selectors for it. Secondly, it's not clear what your goal is. You can easily select the elements and set the `colspan` attribute - but what value should it be set to...?

Comment: Actually the value is to be set after comparing value of firstcol and lastcol, if firstcol is less than 5 and lastcol >=5 but not equal to firstcol we will set colspan by applying some logic.

Comment: That comment makes absolutely no sense with the lack of context or detail in your question. 'firstcol is less than 5' - the value of firstcol? The index? The text content? What even is firstcol? 'we will set colspan by applying some logic', what logic? What value should it use?

Comment: Check the last paragraph of question. In a tag the value of firstcol and lastcol is coming which I need to check at runtime. After that i need to set colspan = lastcol - firstcol -1 
This is logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the `a` element in your `td` like this:

`let a_elem = $('a.fc-day-grid-event', 'td.fc-event-container');`

Use dots (.) looking for class name.

`$(elem, other_elem)` looks for the left hand elem in right hand elem.
If you get an array back, you can use `a_elem[0]`, provided there is only one element of this kind.

Alter the value of colspan:

`$('td.fc-event-container').attr('colspan', your_new_colspan)`

Comment: Based on questions that appear on SO, I wouldn't use `$(find, parent)` with selectors.  There's no problem with it, but there's enough questions where someone wants `$(".a,.b,.c")` and they do `$(".a", ".b", ".c")`.     If using string selectors then no need for comma `$('td.fc-event-container a.fc-day-grid-event')` would be the same.

Comment: `a_elem[0]` will give you a DOM node, so `a_elem[0].jquery_method()` would give an error.

Comment: *"if you get an array back"* is also unclear as *all* jquery objects are the same regardless of how many elements.